# SQL: Write a query to get the average order value by gender

Tags: sql, average

I have two tables: one represents transaction and the other represents customer attributes. "transactions" table has 4 columns: id, user_id, product_id, quantity. "users" table has 3 columns: id, name, sex.

The goal is to write a query to find the average quantity value by gender. I can't quiet get this one. I guess we have to use groupby for gender, and avg() for quantity? I'm new to SQL and I'm not sure how to use these. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried writing a query yet, and, if so, can you include it in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT AVG(t.quantity), u.sex
FROM TRANSACTIONS t
INNER JOIN USERS u ON t.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.sex
```

Answer (score 0):

I think below should work

```
select avg(price), u.sex
from products
join transaction as t
on products.id = t.product_id
join users as u
on t.user_id = u.id
group by u.sex
```

Comment: I forgot what we call this join type .